# Make kable fully reactive in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, reactive, mathjax, kable

Consider the simple example below, it's a bit silly simplified version of what I am currently working with:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)

ui <- fluidPage(

  # I'm not sure whether this is the best code for rendering LaTeX in the table
  withMathJax(),
  tags$script(
    type = "text/x-mathjax-config",
    "MathJax.Hub.Config({
              tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['$$','$$']]}
            });"
  ),
  
  numericInput(inputId = "A", label = "A:", min = 0, max = 10, value = 1), 
  numericInput(inputId = "B", label = "B:", min = 0, max = 10, value = 2), 
  tableOutput("AplusB.table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  AplusB <- reactive({ input$A + input$B })
  
  output$AplusB.table <- renderText({
    tab <- data.frame(
      "And the sum is...", 
      paste0("$", AplusB(), "$")
    )
    
    colnames(tab) <- c(
      "$\\text{Description}$", 
      "$\\sigma=A + B$"
    )
    
    tab %>%
      knitr::kable("html", escape = FALSE, align = 'c') %>%
      kable_styling(full_width = FALSE)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The kable renders well, thanks to the call to withMathJax at the beginning of the ui:

[image]

However, once I change one of the inputs the kable does not render the LaTeX expressions.

It is reactive as it updates the changing inputs, but not reactive in processing the LaTeX parts:

[image]

What am I missing?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I found a way. I don't fully understand what it does, I just put together bits and pieces of what I could find online. I'd still like to understand how this works, or whether there is an easier solution.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)

js <- "
window.MathJax = {
  tex: {
    inlineMath: [['$', '$']], 
    displayMath: [['$$', '$$']],
  }
};
"

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput(inputId = "A", label = "A:", min = 0, max = 10, value = 1), 
  numericInput(inputId = "B", label = "B:", min = 0, max = 10, value = 2), 
  tableOutput("AplusB.final")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  AplusB <- reactive({ input$A + input$B })
  
  AplusB.table <- renderText({
    tab <- data.frame(
      "And the sum is...", 
      paste0("$", AplusB(), "$")
    )
    
    colnames(tab) <- c(
      "$\\text{Description}$", 
      "$\\sigma=A + B$"
    )
    
    tab %>%
      knitr::kable("html", escape = FALSE, align = 'c') %>%
      kable_styling(full_width = FALSE)
  })
  
  output$AplusB.final <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      HTML(AplusB.table()),
      tags$script(HTML(js)),
      tags$script(
        async="",
        src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"
      )
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```